# copy each sheet to separate cls files with path given

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy/save/export each of my sheets to separate vba file (which i would import later).  I intend to do this because, i have a workbook beforeclose event to delete all the worksheets except sheet1.  so before deleting i want all the other sheets to be copied to the specified path. ofcourse the same would be imported via worksheet click or box click event or whatever later.

i tried something like this but it doesnt work!

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC").Export Filename:="C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\vbe\A"ABC".cls
```

can anyone help me with this?
rgds

Comment: cls? Do you mean csv?

Comment: i would like to save the codes of the sheet. i understand that manually we can export the entire sheet to cls file. i want this to be done on runtime. is this possible in any way

Comment: I think `cls` is latex, so this would be an export? There is no native way to do so in excel without an add-in, I don't think

Comment: would you like to suggest me an alternative to save codes/sheet on runtime which can be called for later ?

Comment: hope this help .. http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=359

Answer (score 0):

What you need is VBE.

First, add reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensbility.

Then, I add to enable trust access to the VBA project object model, in macro security settings.

And now, following code will work:

```
Sub Save_cls()
    Dim c As VBComponent
    f = FreeFile
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If c.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule Then
            Open c.Name & ".cls" For Output As f
            Print #f, c.CodeModule.Lines(1, c.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
            Close f
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: *Generic function* - Put it in a VBA module, so it is available to whole workbook and is not attached to single worksheet:

```
Public Sub SaveSheetCode(ByVal Sheet As Worksheet, ByVal Filename As String)
    Dim c As VBComponent, f As Integer
    Set c = Sheet.Parent.VBProject.VBComponents(Sheet.CodeName)
    f = FreeFile
    Open Filename For Output As f
    Print #f, c.CodeModule.Lines(1, c.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
    Close f
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
 ... Anywhere in your book code
 SaveSheetCode WorkSheets("Sheet1"), "C:\VBA\Sheet1.cls"
```

Comment: @LS_dev- this code works under sub. i have a series of events under workbook beforeclose. one such event is to delete the sheets which contains the code. before deleting i want them to be saved in a given file path and name. this file will have to retrieved back to its same position when it is called for later when the workbook is opened and under use. hope your code is set for the same. and 1 more piece of info required can u elaborate of the code in the line starting with print....what exactly the code does?thankss